# find an IP address by MAC address on LAN

Tags: ethernet, nmap

I would like to look up a MAC address on my ethernet and find the IP of that machine. What command should I issue using which app?

edit: i've tried: `fping -g 195.88.88.0/24 | arp -a | grep 4C:12:10:11:35:B4` but that does not work (i checked with my own MAC whether it can find or not)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download and install [arp-scan](http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools-resources/security-tools/arp-scan) - it will return all MAC addresses it can find and their reported IP addresses. Many distros have an arp-scan package in their repositories.

For example, to scan network 192.168.1.0:

```
arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: Finally, a way to find out my wireless AP's address :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, `nmap` can't do this. You may be able to do this by looking at the ARP transactions with `tcpdump`, or on Windows, try using `arp -a` (but only if you've previously communicated with it).

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address may not have an associated IP address, (or its IP address might not be compatible with your hosts network/mask). To get all hosts that can respond, to answer a ping, use 255.255.255.255.

As others have suggested, use `tcpdump -env` to look for ARP and MAC addresses. If you suspect there might be an IP misconfiguration, you can set your ip/netmask to some large netmask (195.88.88. netmask 128.0.0.0, which will likely take you offline.

Ping 255.255.255.255 and see if you get an address resolution.  (This will cover networks from 128 - 255;  set your ip to 10.10.10.10/128.0.0.0 to get the other half of the possible IPv4 addresses.

Comment: please read superuser.com/faq#signatures . You should not sign your posts.